# sending emails with html doesn't work

Tags: php

I need a help. My script sends e-mails, but ignores html tags. Could anyone help me with this?

My code is here:

```
$to  = "email@example.com";
$subject = 'Povolenie užívateľa';
$message = '<html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>
        <body>
        Užívateľ čaká na vaše schválenie.<br>Meno:$meno <br> Priezvisko:$priezvisko <br>
                                    Firma:$firma<br>
                                    E-mail:$email <br> V prípade ak chcete užívateľa povoliť kliknite na tento odkaz: 
                                    <a href="http://website.com/povolenie.php?r=$ret&povolenie=1" target="blank">povoliť</a> <br>
                                    Ak ho povoliť nechcete tak kliknite na tento odkaz: 
                                    <a href="http://website.com/povolenie.php?r=$ret&povolenie=0" target="blank">zakázať</a>"
        </body> 
            </html>';                                


 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; Charset=Windows-1250'       ."\r\n";                            
$headers = 'From: XXX<email@example.com>' . "\r\n" .               
"CC: email@example.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last header is broken, missing a concatenate (*the period*).

```
$headers = 'From: XYZ <email@example.com>' . "\r\n" .               
"CC: email@example.com";
```

add the period/dot

```
$headers .= 'From:...
         ^ right there
```

do:

```
$headers .= 'From: XYZ <email@example.com>' . "\r\n" .               
"CC: email@example.com";
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Now it works. I have one more question yet. Is it possible to send variables in a message? And how?

Comment: Thanks but it already works. I had also mistake in message body. After tag </a> I had useful " and that was the reason why variables were not shown in mail.

Comment: @user3706305 OK, glad to hear it's completely resolved. We can now close the question if you could mark it as solved, cheers.

Comment: @user3706305 Tick the white checkmark till it turns green next to my answer; that's how a question is closed and marked as accepted. You're welcome :)